# Img exceed screen and create a scrollbar at bottom

Tags: css, html

I'm stuck on a problem. 
I added img with this code :

**HTML:**

```css
  .homepage-right {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 46em;
    }

    .river-right {
     padding: 0;
    }

    .img-river-right {
     float: right;
     max-width: 50%;
        -ms-transform: rotate(1deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
        transform: rotate(1deg);
    }
```

```html
<section id="homepage-river-right">
        <div class="homepage-right">
            <div class="col-md-12 river-right">
               <img class="img-river-right" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490644120458-f5e5c71d2ab0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"> 
            </div>
        </div>        
    </section>
```

My problem :
[image]The web problem

The problem is the scrollbar at the bottom.
I know why she appears, because I rotate the img and she exceeds in the right of the screen. My question is how can I cut the img for don't create this scrollbar. Or I can't in CSS and I need to do this with a perfect img in photoshop.

Thanks.

Comment: And you've tried `#homepage-river-right { overflow; hidden; }`?

Comment: yes i tryed it, but no success

Comment: Do you have a link to the webpage?

Comment: Not really, i'm in LocalHost and I'm waiting the final developpements for publish him in production. I have a pre-prod but I can't give it you... sorry

Comment: @Paulo Wllier created a code snippet of your code. can you please tell me what is going wrong

Comment: The scrollbar at the bottom is going wrong. Because my image is not perfect, and i need to rotate her for being perfectlly straight and without white space at his right.

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow` `hidden` on `.river-right`

```
.river-right {
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Ok it's running. Thanks for solve my problem bro' :)

Comment: overflox-x: hidden   Otherwise your site is not scrollable anymore